# "Quirk" vs. "Oddity"

Tags: word-meaning, difference

What is the practical difference between the words "quirk" and "oddity"?

I do understand they are very common and propably can be used interchangeably in many contexts, but here are some examples:

> - *Words at Play: Quips, Quirks & Oddities* - a book by O. V. Michaelsen
> - *C++ Quirks, Oddities, and Incidentals* - a chapter in a book by Marc Gregoire
> - *Quirks and Oddities May Be Mild Forms of Psychiatric Illness* - an article by Jane Brody

So it seems these words are not complete synonyms.

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary? If so, what are you still uncertain about?

Comment: Yes, I checked the Cambridge dictionary before asking. I was uncertain because, as I said, these words are used side-by-side in some titles.

Comment: What are you still uncertain about? The words have different meanings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common to use two or more words that have essentially identical meaning in a title, it feels more comprehensive. So this kind of use should not be taken as evidence for significant difference in meaning.

#### Quirk

The relevant sense (b) of ["quirk" from Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quirk) is:

> : a peculiar trait : idiosyncrasy

Other senses are:

> - a : an abrupt twist or curve
> - c : accident, vagary *a quirk of fate*

The [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/quirk) gives

> an unusual habit or part of someone's personality, or something that is strange and unexpected:

I believe the sense of "curve or twist" is the oldest, and other sense derived from that sense.

#### Odity

For "oddity" [Merriam-Webster gives](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oddity):

> - 1 : an odd person, thing, event, or trait
> - 2 : the quality or state of being odd

It also lists as synonyms:

> crotchet, curiosity, eccentricity, erraticism, idiosyncrasy, individualism, kink, mannerism, peculiarity, quiddity, quip, **quirk**, singularity, tic, trick, twist

The [Cambridge dictionary gives for oddity](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/oddity):

> someone or something that is strange and unusual:

#### Conclusion

I cannot see any significant difference between the meaning or usage of "quirk"and "oddity" in this sense; the choice is simply a matter of style.  I cannot think of an example where one could be naturally used and the other could not be substituted with no significant change of meaning.